# How to position the Text Frame above the table

Tags: migradoc

I am trying to position the addressTextFrame above my table and for some reason appears underneath it.

```
public void DefineInvoice(Document document)
        {
            Section section = document.AddSection();
            // create the text frame for address
            TextFrame addressFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
            addressFrame.Height = "3.0cm";
            addressFrame.Width = "7.0cm";
            addressFrame.Left = ShapePosition.Left;
            addressFrame.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
            addressFrame.Top = "5.0cm";
            addressFrame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;

            //fill in address for text frame
            Paragraph paragraph = addressFrame.AddParagraph();
            paragraph.AddText("Nieto LLC");
            paragraph.AddLineBreak();
            paragraph.AddText("6110 Google Drive");
            paragraph.AddLineBreak();
            paragraph.AddText("Houston, TX 77309");
            paragraph.AddLineBreak();
            paragraph.AddText("P: 281-890-5899");

            //define table
            Table table = section.AddTable();



            table.Borders.Width = 0.75;

}
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Invoice]

I am learning as I go having never worked with this new technology nor C#. I thought LastSection() puts things last but I get the same result when doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the address at the absolute vertical position of 5 cm. I assume that address and table would overlap if there were more items (rows) in the table.

If you want to have the address above the table, do not set an absolute position for the address, just let it float in the main body text.